# Where to find a modal window/box that is similar to Pinterest's scrollable modal box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, simplemodal, pinterest

I am having a hard time looking for a modal box that has a similar functionality as the one on Pinterest.

I am currently using simple-modal (jQuery) but the problems are the height is not dynamic (putting `height: auto` has some problems) and the modal box's position is fixed at the center. Hence, if the content is long, it will just have a scrollbar on its own (inside the modal box) instead of being scrollable using the browser's main scrollbar. When I use the main browser's scrollbar, it's scrolling the content behind the modal (which is the actual web page) which is not what I intend to happen.

Do you have any suggestions on what to use?

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on a object and open it as a new tab/window, you will then see what **Pinterest** is overlaying on the main page.

That said, you might achieve the same effect by expanding a full viewport `iframe` with semi-transparent background to see the underlying page.

To be sure, I've not come across any lightbox [clones](http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/) similar to Pinterest's custom jQuery version hidden somewhere in it's [**.js file**](http://jsfiddle.net/PWLvQ/).

---

**Status Update:** 
If your willing to create your own method, I've outlined a process seen in my SO Answer [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11253923/1195891)